# Best method to send data to Microsoft Azure IoT central from multiple devices

Tags: azure, azure-iot-central

I am looking for advice as to the best way to send data from multiple devices to IoT central.

To explain, I will be deploying 3-6 IoT connected microprocessors that will send data from multiple attached sensors to IoT central.

I will be doing this at just one location at first but eventually will be deploying these sensor networks at multiple locations. Each of these locations will need to have a personalized dashboard to view their sensor network data.

I am looking for any advice as to the best method to send this data to IoT central.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I should at that I will be using Partcile IO devices (Electrons) to send the data. I am curious if webhooks would be a good option.

Comment: webhooks might not be best for benefiting from all the features. however, it's good enough for sending telemetry. see -> https://github.com/Azure/iot-central-firmware/tree/master/HttpOnly

Answer (score 1):

Azure IoT Central recently released [Device bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-build-iotc-device-bridge) which is an open-source solution that can be used to connect Sigfox, Particle, The Things Network, and other clouds to your Azure IoT Central app. You can access the open source solution from [Github](https://aka.ms/iotcentralgithubdevicebridge).